# Android Spring Jackson Mapping: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, spring, rest, jackson

i'm trying to let my android application function as a REST Client. Basically i followed this example: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-basic-auth/client/src/org/springframework/android/basicauth .

I am developing for Android 2.3 and above. I added

```
spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-auth-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar and
jackson-mini-1.9.11.jar
```

to my buildpath.

Anyway I always get these errors

```
11-26 19:01:24.461: E/dalvikvm(15994): Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper', referenced from method org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.<init>
11-26 19:01:24.480: E/AndroidRuntime(15994): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-26 19:01:24.480: E/AndroidRuntime(15994): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
```

in the second line of this code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Iris

Comment: Jackson mini has no mapping functionality... Use "full" (core + mapper)version

Comment: Unless you know all of your intricate dependencies, you can safely use jackson-all-x.x.x.jar, which contains the uber set of dependencies. Last I checked, the latest version available was 1.9.11. Located here: [http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload). Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was (as Selvin stated in his comment) to include the full jackson instead of the jackson mini library. 
Thanks again Selvin.

Answer (score 5):

If you get `NoClassDefFoundError` during Runtime, then I suspect you did not include the .jar files to work at runtime. You have to check the checkbox for each .jar like this:

[image]